# Excluding bad bots via htaccess: why I get http 500 errors?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm blocking bad and useless bot using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 360Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} A(?:ccess|ppid) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} C(?:apture|lient|opy|rawl|url) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} D(?:ata|evSoft|o(?:main|wnload)) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} E(?:ngine|zooms) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} f(?:etch|ilter) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} genieo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Ja(?:karta|va) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Li(?:brary|nk|bww) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} nutch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Pr(?:oxy|ublish) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} robot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} s(?:craper|istrix|pider) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} W(?:get|(?:in(32|Http))) [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

Complete htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on

#inherit from root htaccess and append at last, necessary in root too
RewriteOptions inherit

#block bad bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 360Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} A(?:ccess|ppid) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} C(?:apture|lient|opy|rawl|url) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} D(?:ata|evSoft|o(?:main|wnload)) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} E(?:ngine|zooms) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} f(?:etch|ilter) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} genieo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Ja(?:karta|va) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Li(?:brary|nk|bww) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} nutch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Pr(?:oxy|ublish) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} robot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} s(?:craper|istrix|pider) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} W(?:get|(?:in(32|Http))) [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]

#include caching for images
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 360 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"  
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nix.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nix.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.foo\.com\/nix\.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gallery.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gallery.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.foo\.com\/gallery\.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blog.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.foo\.com\/blog" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^id.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.id.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/foo\.myopenid\.com\/" [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /map.php http://www.foo.com/maps/map.php

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(map(?!pa_area51\.)[^/.]+\.php)$ http://www.foo.com/maps/$1

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It worked good (http 403) until I switched from a Litespeed webserver hosting to an Apache's one. They're both shared hosting services. Now I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /robots.txt on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Here's a sample from access log:

```
208.115.111.68 - - [22/Sep/2013:17:56:48 +0200] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 576 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Ezooms/1.0; ezooms.bot@gmail.com)"
```

Any hints on that http 500 error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: grant access first to the user or group on the file

Comment: This is mot complete .htaccess. Post complete code here.

Comment: @drabo2005: CHMOD on htaccess file is 644.

Comment: @anubhava: Added in the first post

Comment: You can see request of `/robots.txt` log which should not generate this 403. Why not block these bots from `robots.txt` and keep .htaccess simple.

Comment: Check the error log as well.

Comment: @anubhava because one of the reasons behind those bots being renamed "malicious" is that most of them don't evev follow robots.txt directives, even if they should. I pasted a line containing "ezooms" bot, but there are other dozens of them who can only be blocked via IP or USER_AGENT method.

Comment: @CBroe Actually, that line I copied from access log has been taken from the error log

Comment: That not how the default error log lines look – but the access log lines.

Comment: @flapane: Please check http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml#.UkBH8WSKI7s for blocking bad bots. Your rule's regex different from this one.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, of course you're right. It wasn't an error log, but a filter who showed lines containing http 500 messages in the access log. Here's what the error log says: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`. I'm on a shared web hosting, so I'm not I can alter debug levels.

Comment: @anubhava the regex rules should already be fine. The article just uses a slightly different method.

Comment: I doubt that this stems from your bot-blocking rules. I think it’s rather the following redirecting rules: In most of them you are rewriting “everything” (`^(.*)$`) to a .php file – but those rules will match that .php file itself again in the next round … and so you have an endless redirect. To avoid that, you should check first if the request already matches an existing file. Btw., there is no need to escape characters in the substitution string, because that is not a regular expression.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure I got it. How is (in this case) /nix.php matched by this rule? Isn't it just a target to redirect to anybody wanting to access nix.foo.com/bar ?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nix.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nix.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.foo.com/nix.php" [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Even from me was hard deal with RewriteCond to block bots immediately use SetEnvIfNoCase Like this :-

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^.*360Spider.*$ bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent A(?:ccess|ppid) bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent C(?:apture|lient|opy|rawl|url) bad_bot

Order deny,allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

and do the rest .. this will give bad bots 403 error message .